# Cant authorize mongo from remote connection

Tags: mongodb, networking

I am connecting to a remote mongo server using "mongo xx.xx.xx.xxx:27017"

it is connecting no problem. but when try to authenticate using db.auth({username,password}) it gives 0.

But when i go over to that remote machine and run a local client there and try auth. it works fine.

Please help. what could be the issue

Comment: What does the log say? Try with `mongo --username your_username --password your_password xx.xx.xx.xxx:27017 `

Comment: Maybe you are on the wrong machine. Double check the ip.

Comment: i cant find any log for mongo request... one that i found logs only db requests...and i have double checked the ip.

in my case i can connect to mongo shell from remote but unable to authenticate the admin.

Comment: What's the error message when you connect to the remote mongo server and authenticate the user? Which database are you connecting to and authenticating the user? Which database is the user in?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you forgot to run "use admin" or "use " before you run db.auth command.

Comment: No. I have the same problem. I selected the right db using the `use` command. Mongo v3.0.3